# What does `fd01h/64769d` mean in Device and `142368` in Inode?

Tags: bash, devices, inode

When I checked the state of a file:

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# stat test.py
  File: ‘test.py’
  Size: 33          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 142368      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-11-09 20:42:30.262438217 +0800
Modify: 2018-11-09 20:42:27.266329005 +0800
Change: 2018-11-09 20:42:27.269329115 +0800
 Birth: -
```

What does `fd01h/64769d` mean in Device and `142368` in Inode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Device:

`Device: fd01h/64769d` tells you on which device the file you examined is. The value is represented both as **h**exadecimal (`fd01`) and **d**ecimal (`64769`) number.

Now each device is identifiable by its **major and minor number**. The major number identifies a class of devices, which normally use the same driver/kernel module, whereas the minor number identifies a unique device within that class.

Note that in this context, "device" is not necessarily a hardware device here though, it includes virtual devices. Everything in `/dev` is a device actually (except for the directories and symlinks) and has a major and minor number. You can check them yourself with `ls -l /dev` (shortened example output):

```
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root          4560 Nov 14 00:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x  27 root root          4096 Nov  2 03:30 ../
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,     0 Nov 14 01:06 sda
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,     1 Nov 14 01:06 sda1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,     2 Nov 14 01:06 sda2
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,     3 Nov 14 01:06 sda3
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,    16 Nov 14 01:06 sdb
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,    17 Nov 14 01:06 sdb1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,    18 Nov 14 01:06 sdb2
crw-------   1 root root     10,   224 Nov 13 15:53 tpm0
crw-------   1 root root    253, 65536 Nov 13 15:53 tpmrm0
crw-rw-rw-   1 root tty       5,     0 Nov 14 01:06 tty
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,     0 Nov 13 15:53 tty0
crw--w----   1 root tty       4,     1 Nov 13 15:53 tty1
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,     5 Nov 13 15:53 zero
```

The fourth and fifth columns here show the major and minor numbers. For regular hard disks, the major number is 8 and each of the disks and partitions has its own unique minor number among them.

Now back to your `stat` output, the hexadecimal device number was `fd01`. This can be split up into two bytes, `fd` (decimal 253) is the major number component and `01` (decimal 1) is the minor number. We could try to look up the major number in [this list](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt), but it is only classified as part of a range of numbers for "RESERVED FOR DYNAMIC ASSIGNMENT" and "LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE". I would guess on an encrypted or LVM volume.

Anyway, you can use `lsblk` and check which of the storage block devices listed there corresponds to this major and minor number. You will see this is of course the device/partition/file system on which your examined file actually is stored.

See also: [Device number in stat command output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4309882/4464570)

---

### Inode:

On Unix file systems like ext4, the default for Ubuntu, each file system object (like files and directories) is described by a so-called "inode". It is basically a data structure that stores which blocks on the disk belong to the object, but also metadata like timestamps as well as owner and permission information. Each object has (at least) one inode, and each inode belongs to exactly one file system object.

The number you see in your `stat` output is the number or index of this file's inode, which therefore lets you uniquely identify the file. E.g. `debugfs` could be used to show that this number is correctly corresponding to the file you examined by searching for the path, knowing only the number.

See also: [Inode (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)